# Is there way to flag if there is a missing column or columns in between non-missing columns in SAS?

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

I tried different ways and searched on google to come up with a way to deal with this. But was unable to accomplish this.

Currently, my data looks like the below:

```
data Have;
input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $ col5 $ col6 $ col7 $ col8 $ col9 $ col10 $;
cards;
A B B C . D A . A . 
B A . C A D A B . . 
A B B D D D . . . . 
A . B C B D A . . . 
A B B C . D A . . . 
;
```

**Goal:**
I want to flag all rows that have a missing column in between. For example, if there is a column 2 missing, where col1 - col8 is the series here.
Important to remember that there might be instances where the sequence finishes at col5 or col4 or col6. The rest of the columns would be missing values. We need to ignore these and only flag if there is a missing column or columns in between non-missing columns.

```
data Have;
    input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $ col5 $ col6 $ col7 $ col8 $ col9 $ col10 $ flag$;
    cards;
                         flag
    A B B C . D A . A .   1
    B A . C A D A B . .   1
    A B B D D D . . . .   0
    A . B C B D A . . .   1
    A B B C . D A . . .   1
    ;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you want to do if the first value is missing, but there is no gap once the non-missing values start? .Should a list like `.ABCD...` by flagged or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop until you find a missing value followed by a non-missing value.

Example:

```
data want (drop=index);
  set have;
  array col col1-col10;
  do index = 1 to dim(col)-1 until (flag);
    flag = missing(col(index)) and not missing(col(index+1)) ;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: You don't need the  `FLAG OR` since you will stop when you find a match.

Comment: Hey Richard, can you please explain what this code block is doing? I follow some of it, want to make sure I understand the process.

Comment: Describe what you understand and not sure of and I can correct or amend.